# How to use \ifnum for arguments (expanding macros)?

Tags: macros, counters, expansion

I want to count my `section`'s, `figure`'s etc. using the `totcount` package. To get a general useable template I want to show only counters which are larger than zero. But it seems that `total{counter}` would not evaluated.

I tried the following but none of the both `hide` calls generate any output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{section}

\newcommand{\hide}[2] {
  \ifnum0<0#1
    #2
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}

% should print "Sections: 3" but doesn't show anything
\hide{\total{section}}{Sections: \total{section}}
% should print nothing
\hide{\total{figure}}{Figures: \total{figure}}

\end{document}
```

If I wrote the numbers manually it works like expected:

```
% prints "Sections: 3"
\hide{3}{Sections: \total{section}}
% prints nothing
\hide{0}{Figures: \total{figure}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to get the expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macro `\total` of package is not expandable, it starts with a definition. Use `\totvalue` instead, it maps the name to the internal counter register that can be used with `\ifnum`. From `totcount.sty`:

> ```
> %%   Returns the numeric total value of a registered total counter that is
> %%   passed as argument. Note that if the counter's value is not yet computed
> %%   (at the first time \LaTeX\ runs on the document) this macro returns |-1|.
> \newcommand\totvalue[1]{\value{#1@totc}}
> ```

Example file (I have added the missing `\regtotcounter{figure}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{section}
\regtotcounter{figure}

\newcommand{\hide}[2] {
  \ifnum\totvalue{#1}>0
    #2
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}

% should print "Sections: 3"
\hide{section}{Sections: \total{section}}
% should print nothing
\hide{figure}{Figures: \total{figure}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, I have to read the documentation more carefully.